# Аргументы функции от нескольких переменных в matlab

Tags: matlab

Например есть функция `f = @(x, y, z)x+y+z;` и есть вектор входных значений `par = [x1; y1; z1]`, можно ли как то передать этот вектор как параметр, но что бы он воспринимался как значения аргументов, а не вектор точек, в которых надо вычислить функцию?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужна функция [num2cell](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/num2cell.html):

```
tmp = num2cell(par)
f(tmp{:})
```

См. [Splice vector into arguments for function call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11461963/matlab-splice-vector-into-arguments-for-function-call).

Comment: Спасибо, работает.